# Average time between 2 Dates ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I want to calculate the average time (in days) between 2 dates. I want to know for each user number of days since they joined and get the average.

```
(Date.today  -  User.first.created_at.to_date).to_i
```

Works great for a given user. Now I want to loop through all my users and retrieve the average. How to accomplish such thing?

Comment: Or you can write a query to retrieve the average from db directly.

Comment: What the query would look like in this case?

Comment: something on the lines of `SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(NOW(), created_at))/COUNT(id) FROM users` if you are using MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff, http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
User.all.map{|u| (Date.today - u.created_at.to_date).to_i}.sum/User.count
```

Comment: Not working I got this error undefined method `+' for #<User:0x0000010467f110>

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
User.all.sum { |user| (Time.now - user.created_at) / 1.day }.to_i / User.count
```

Btw if you extend Ruby's `Array` like so:

```
class Array
  def avg(&block)
    sum(&block).to_i / count
  end
end
```

you can do a nice and short version:

```
User.all.avg { |user| (Time.now - user.created_at) / 1.day }
```

Comment: But that would iterate over all users, and would be a big hit if there lots of users.

Comment: Yes, thats right, but writing it in SQL is very database dependent. I think such problems must be independently solved, every app needs it's own solution. Sometimes iterating through Ruby 'Array's is not bad at all, sometimes it can really be a pain in the ass.